# Is there a way to stretch sigmoid function output

Tags: data-transformation, outliers, function, sigmoid-curve

I have an array of values and a value that lies outside of array's max value:

```
arr = [10, 15, 20, 30]
value = 150
```

and I want to make that value less of an outlier, by applying some sort of function to it. Let's say that I want to make that value no more than maximum value of array (limit for outliers is `max(arr)`.

I think that sigmoid function is a good candidate for that transformation, but sigmoid's output is between 0 and 1.
Is there any way for me to pass upper and lower limits to sigmoid (or any other function), so it will transform values from outside the limits to a smaller values?

Something like:

```
arr = [10, 15, 20, 30]
value = 150
transformed_value = 28  # less than upper bound of 30 but smaller that 150
```

Question background:

I am predicting car price based on it's mileage (and other features), using huber regression My array is all the mileages in a train set. But when my model predicts a new object, sometimes that car has a reeealy big mileage, and it screws up my linear regression output. Basically I want to do some non-linear transformation on that mileage, to make huge mileages less of an outliers.

Comment: Could you give us more context?  Where does the problem arise? What are you trying to do? You seem to be describing the solution without mentioning the problem to be solved.

Comment: I am predicting car price based on it's mileage (and other features), using huber regression
My array is all the mileages in a train set. But when my model predicts a new object, sometimes that car has a reeealy big mileage, and it screws up my linear regression output. Basically I want to do some non-linear transformation on that mileage, to make huge mileages less of an outliers.

Comment: Welcome to cv, Cyril - your reply to @Tim's comment is really valuable :-). You could add it to your question, as a last paragraph "Background" or so. Generally phrased questions here would typically allow many possible answers,  which is why hardly anyone dares to answer. Giving context helps to decide which of these many answers would be suitable and increases your chance to get an answer to your question.

Comment: You can always use `min(predicted, max(arr))` to "round down" the prediction. However, if I were you. I'd worry more about finding *why* does the model overpredict. This sounds like either problem with the model or the data. "Hacking" the result is a short-term solution, but it might fail in the long run.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! 
Yeah, I can do that, but that just cuts all the mileages bigger that what was seen in train set. I however, still want my model to extrapolate for bigger mileages, but to do it a bit less severe. For example, if the biggest mileage seen is 150k km, i still want my model to say that a car with 300k km is cheaper, but not twice as much or something. Because the effect of that feature is non-linear (car looses it's value fast for the first 100k km, but much lesser for next 100k kms...)

Comment: Transformations of a variable such as square root or log are standard in regression. Concave transformations such as these have the effect that extreme values on the positive side are brought closer to the majority of the data. Maybe that can deal with your problem.

Comment: Why is it an issue in general that sigmoid output is between 0 and 1? If you use the variable as predictor, it doesn't really matter whether values are between 0 and 1 or 0 and 1000. Regression is affine equivariant, implying that if you multiply any variable with any factor, results will still be equivalent.

Comment: Robust Huber regression isn't as useful as quantile regression in predicting extreme values. The advantage with QR is that you can explore a range of possible quantiles as opposed to the median value, eventually settling on one that minimizes error and loss. Alternatives to log or square root transformations which compress the pdf of the features include inverse hyperbolic sine functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions and power transformations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer that explains how to stretch a sigmoid function:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242042/stretch-sigmoid-along-horizontal-x-interval

my function for transforming the value looks like this:

```
def custom_sigmoid(value, max_arr ):
    r = 3  # bigger r - the steeper the surve
    N = max_of_arr  # upper bound, for example the maximum value of an array
    g = r * (2 * value - N) / N
    return int(1/(1+math.exp(-g)) * N)
```